# Memory management in objective c/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am new to iPhone application development. I was doing .NET, C# development before. I have few questions in memory management in iPhone and objective c. I hope some one can clear these questions I have.

Q1) 
if I assign to a variable like this do I have to release it?

```
NSString *line = @""; // is this a correct way of doing things? 

[line release]; // do i have to release it?
```

Q2)

```
NSString *line2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

NSString *line3 = line2;

[line2 release];
```

Here I know line2 has to be released. But do I have to release line3? Or what would happen to line3 after releasing line2?

Q3)
I have a variable declared in .h file like

```
NSString *line5;
```

Then I have it

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *line5;
```

what does this mean?
Do I have to do this to use variables?
What is the meaning of nonatomic and retain?

Q4)
What does `@synthesize line5;` do

Q5)

```
-(void) myFunction
{
    NSString *line2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

    line5 = line2;

    [line2 release]; 
}
```

Here what would happen to line5 after calling this function? Will it exist? How do I make the value available after calling the function?

Q6)

```
-(NSString*) myFunction2
{
    NSString *line2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];


    return line2;
}
```

how do I define a function that return string and make it exist outside the function?

How do I call this function to get a string output?

Comment: Honestly you asked tons of question, and it's hard to repson clearly to them. It's alway better to split it.

Comment: Useful ressources : [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

Comment: And [Learning Objective-C Declared properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html)

Comment: as for line2 and line3, they're both pointers to the same object, so no, once you release line2, you should not release line3.  However to be safe, you should do line3 = nil; to ensure you don't reference a released object later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1) if I assign to a variable like this do I have to release it?

```
NSString *line = @""; // is this a correct way of doing things? 

[line release]; // do i have to release it?
```

**Answer** No @"" is a macro that creates an autorelease NSString

Q2)

```
NSString *line2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

NSString *line3 = line2;

[line2 release];
```

**Answer** You create line2 (with init) hence you have to release it. You don't have to release line3 since it's only pointing to line2 so you would over release line2.

Q3) I have a variable declared in .h file like

`NSString *line5;`
Then I have it

`@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *line5;`
what does this mean? Do I have to do this to use variables? What is the meaning of nonatomic and retain?

**Answer** You can think of `@property` as an behaviour definition of your property, so that when you use the `@synthezie` the compiler will know how to interpret the getters and setters for this property.

Q4) What does `@synthesize` line5; do

**Answer** Creates getters and setters for your declared property based on the options chosen in `@property(option,option...)`

Q5)

```
-(void) myFunction
{
    NSString *line2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

    line5 = line2;

    [line2 release]; 
}
```

Here what would happen to line5 after calling this function? Will it exist? How do I make the value available after calling the function?

**Answer** the function creates a new line2, then it assigns line5 as a pointer to line2 and then you release line2 which is a problem b/c line5 is now pointing to nothing. You should retain line5 to be able to still point to line2.

How do I call this function to get a string output?

**Answer** you call this function like this:

```
[self myFunction2];
```

**Finaly** you should read this memory management http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1

Answer (score 0):

simple the concept is

if use to create the object with alloc , copy ,retain then only u have responsibility to release them.

so

use [object release];

otherwise dont worry about that

more over while return with alloc ushould use autorelease

-(NSString*) myFunction2
{
    NSString *line2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

```
return [line2 autorelease];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Q1`. No. When you assign NSSting with @"", its an autorelease object.

`Q2`. No. `line2` points to `line3`. So I think its already released. Check by running, you will get a bad access error, when you access a released object.

`Q3`. `nonatomic` works with `synchronization` in threads. `retain` will increase your object's retain count to 1. In short, if you retain any variable, you must release it yourselves.

`Q4`. `@synthesize line5;` gives you accessor method written automatically. i.e. you do not need to write these, but you get it.
if `line5` is a `NSString` var,

```
- (NSString *) line5 {
.....
return line5;
}

- (void) setLine5:(NSString *) aLine {
self.line5 = aLine;
}
```

`Q5`. This will result a bad access error. 
For short answer is, you can use

```
line5 = [line2 copy];
```

But then, you have to release `line5` somewhere in your class.

`Q6`.

```
-(NSString*) myFunction2
{
    NSString *line2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
    return line2;
}
```

This will return an auto released string.

Answer (score 0):

q1) NO
q2) if you release line2 the content in line 3 will also be released as you have not allocated it
q3) As you have retained line5 you need to release it, retain is like allocation as you think, and the nonatomic means other threads from other methods can acesss it till the operation on that valuable is completed, means if you make it atomic it will be synchronized means it will have semaphore works like a key and if other threads wants to perform updating on that variable, that thread needs to have that semaphore.

synthesize is what you do indirectly is 
suppose if you synthesize line5, it means, 
(void)setLine5:(NSString *)line5{
self.line5 = line5 }